# Jupyter notebook : kernel restarts suddenly

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0, jupyter-lab

I use Jupyter lab and Jupyter Notebook for my Deep Learning programs, so I made some long runs in order to train my models. But for some weeks, I've had recurrent kernel restarts after hours of training, which is very annoying. In addition, very few informations are given by the server console or by the browser log :

Jupyter-lab server log :

```
[I 2021-02-26 00:40:03.756 ServerApp] AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
kernel 1330ee40-a826-44e2-9be9-f123deeaa1b2 restarted
[I 2021-02-26 00:40:04.070 ServerApp] Starting buffering for 1330ee40-a826-44e2-9be9-f123deeaa1b2:1b7fa111-f2d2-4804-bd90-c81e26562254
[I 2021-02-26 00:40:04.112 ServerApp] Restoring connection for 1330ee40-a826-44e2-9be9-f123deeaa1b2:1b7fa111-f2d2-4804-bd90-c81e26562254
```

I have the same problem when I use Jupyter-notebook instead of Jupyter-lab.

Various remarks :

- The server and the client are not on the same machine, therefore I use ssh to connect to the server as described [here](https://amber-md.github.io/pytraj/latest/tutorials/remote_jupyter_notebook).
- I work under a corporation proxy
- I use Tensorflow 2 for Deep Learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I thing I found the error's cause -> It was certainly a little memory leak in the code I was running which caused program crash after hundreds of epochs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure, you can run it in nohup mode (background process). It will run your jupyter notebook script on the remote server even if you are disconnected to it.

You can run in nohup mode by looking at this small tutorial:
https://gist.github.com/33eyes/e1da2d78979dc059433849c466ff5996

Comment: Thanks it's a good idea, I will try it on Monday and I give feedbacks on Thursday. However, I'm not sure about this solution because I have no trace of disconnection on server side, even the jupyter process is still running, it's only the kernel which is restarting.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow related:
I have also seen this issue when using CUDA-DL libraries in Jupyter Notebooks created from Kubeflow:

```
AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
```

In this case, it is due to a lack of memory assigned to the pod Kubeflow creates to deploy the Jupyter Server.
The solution is as simple as allocating more memory (from ~4Gi) when creating the Notebook (and avoiding memory leaks in code :) )

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but some kind of troubleshooting:

- Run notebook from the beginning but only until certain cell.
- Walk up/down until you find where it fails.
- If it wasn't failing before, think what have you added.

In my case, I added

`test_eq(dill.pickles(var),True) # Checks that it can be pickled`

the `dill.pickles`, outside/inside the test would keep causing the restart, but not necessarily when running that line, could be a few silly lines after. (weird, I know).

I checked the RAM and looked as expected.

Commenting it out resolved the issue. (Can't imagine why).

Now I test with

```
pp=dill.loads(dill.dumps(al_es))
test_eq(is_a_valid_object(pp),True)
# is_a_valid_object is my own function
# test_eq is from fastcore.test.test_eq
```